# cannot redirect after mysqli connection error

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to php. I am trying to redirect to a error page in php when I get a mysql connection error, but I get an error stating that I cannot modify the header because the output was already sent on line 8 (where I created the connection). Please can you advise on the proper way of doing this?

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost:3306";
$username = "danny";
$password = "sql1";
$dbname = "testdb";

  try{
      $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
  }
  catch(Exception $e){
  header('Location: /connection_error.php');
  die();
}


?>
```

Thanks

Danny

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add this line at the top to tell mysqli to throw exceptions

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT); 
$servername = "localhost:3306";
$username = "danny";
$password = "sql1";
$dbname = "testdb";

  try{
      $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
  }
  catch(Exception $e){
  header('Location: /connection_error.php');
  die();
}
```

Comment: thank you this worked. Can I close the connection in the catch block

Comment: @DannyR The connection is not opened; that is why it got into Exception

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, you can always check the error code from the last connect call by using [mysqli::$connect_errno](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-errno.php), whereas it returns an error code value for the last call, if it failed. Zero means no error occurred (hence the falsey).

```
<?php
    /* Variable Defaults */
    $servername = 'localhost:3306';
    $username   = 'danny';
    $password   = 'sql1';
    $dbname     = 'testdb';

    /* Make Connection */
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    /* Check Connection */
    if($conn->connect_errno) {
        /* Redirect */
        header('Location: /connection_error.php');
        exit();
    }
?>
```

Comment: If your `mysqli` call is displaying a notice, you will not be able to use `header()` since the headers have already been sent. I would suggest modifying your `error_reporting` to not display notices.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<?php
ob_start();

$servername = "localhost:3306";
$username = "danny";
$password = "sql1";
$dbname = "testdb";

  try{
      $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
  }
  catch(Exception $e){
  header('Location: /connection_error.php');
}

ob_flush();
?>
```

Comment: Flushing the buffer makes no difference in this case.

Comment: It's not going at all to catch the error, because the connection will be stopped and give warning that access denied.